# Are there any published guidelines on how to chop up monsters for use as alchemical components?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, alchemy

I have a character with the Guild Artisan background. His guild was an Alchemists' Guild so he is proficient with the alchemist's tool kit.  I mentioned to the DM that I could theoretically chop up monster corpses for use as alchemical raw materials and he said it was a good idea but provided no guidance.

Is there any published material that explains how to do this in 5th edition? Because the last time I saw guidelines, they were in the AD&D Dungeon Master's Guide.

Comment: Would lore answers or answers from older edition be acceptable? And what about 3rd party published material? Also, I took liberty to edit your title a little bit and add [tag:alchemy] tag. Feel free to roll back if you disagree.

Comment: I hope this question is happy with older lore, I would be tempted to raise my own version if not, this is a really good question!

Comment: I believe that due to the fact this is focused on 5e and Published Material, there shouldn't be heavy references to old lore, lest it be off-topic. I've got an idea for an answer however I'll need to reference some books like XGTE first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there rules for disassembling a slain creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138255/are-there-rules-for-disassembling-a-slain-creature) I also know there was *some* other question on this and the answers mentioned lizardfolk but I can't seem to find it

Comment: That linked question is very dragon focused, the answers might end up the same, but this is a wider question.